Ionic iOS PWA Status Bar with translucent headers
I have a PWA I'm working on using the ionic framework.
It looks just like an iOS app apart from one thing that I can't figure out and that's the status bar.
On the ionic component documentation the examples show the background of the header matching that of the status bar, which is exactly what I'm trying to achieve but for me the status bar is always solid black (in light mode) and white in dark mode.
I have tried to implement the collapsable headers, which gives a nice translucent background effect but I cannot get the status bar to match.
I have tried to add extra meta tags like
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover"></meta>
or
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
Which have not made any difference, but given that my manifest file has display set to standalone, they shouldn't be needed.
I have been able to change the color using the theme_color property in the manifest but that is a set color and will not match the translucent behavior of the header.
This is an example of how it displays as a PWA


And this is how it displays in the browser


The PWA is written using React, without using Capacitor so as I understand it I cannot use the status bar plugin
Any guidance or other things to try would be greatly appreciated

You need to use the @capacitor/status-bar plugin.The doc even states this at the very beginning:

The StatusBar API Provides methods for configuring the style of the Status Bar, along with showing or hiding it.


Ok, then I don't think I can get my desired behaviour. Just thought it'd be possible based on all the examples on the site. If I understand that plugin correctly then I would need to make an actual app, which is not something we need at the moment

Your PWA IS an actual app already. Progressive.Web.App.

Sorry, I meant not a native iOS app, which I need it to be to use that status bar plugin
